# XAMPP Control Panel keeps deleting itself, how can I fix this?

Tags: xampp

I've been experiencing a frustrating issue with XAMPP where the XAMPP control panel keeps deleting itself from the xampp folder, even after multiple uninstallations and reinstalls. This has been happening consistently and I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it? I've checked my antivirus software and there don't seem to be any conflicts there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.